# Matplotlib: how to call a pick_event only upon a left-click button_press_event?

Tags: matplotlib, handler, interactive, picker

I have a simple interactive plot with a button_press_event and a pick_event handler:

```
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    line, = ax1.plot(x, y, picker=10)

    def pick_handler(event):
        print "Pick_handler called!"
        if isinstance(event.artist, Line2D):
            # do something

    def click_handler(event):
        if event.button == 1:
            print "Click_handler called by left-click!"
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', pick_handler)
        if event.button == 3:
            print "Click_handler called by right-click!"
            # do something

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', click_handler)
    plt.show()
```

The desired behaviour is the following: only if I do a left-click in the plot, the `pick_handler()` should be called.

The given code behaves not as desired, there are several strange things happening.

1) When the plot appears and I do the first left-click anywhere in the plot, the `click_handler()` is called and `print "Click_handler called by left-click!"` is executed, but the `pick_handler()` is not called; only beginning with the second left-click the `pick_handler()` is called.

2) When I do the second and any further left-click anywhere in the plot, the `click_handler()` first calls the `pick_handler()` and only after that `print "Click_handler called by left-click!"` is executed, but according to the code it should be vice versa.

3) When the plot appears and my very first click is a right-click anywhere in the plot (aynwhere means even if I right-click some `Line2D` object), the code acts correctly – it just calls the `click_handler()` and executes `print "Click_handler called by right-click!"`. But if my very first click is a left-click anywhere in the plot, and the second click is a right-click on some `Line2D` object in the plot, then the code calls the `click_handler()`, the `click_handler()` first calls and fully executes the `pick_handler()` and then executes `print "Click_handler called by right-click!"`, but according to the code the `pick_handler()` should never be called by any right-click.

Is my code wrong or is my understanding of click- and pick-handlers wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code is doing what you wanted:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
line, = ax1.plot(x, y, 'o', picker=10)

def pick_handler(event):
    print("Pick_handler called!")
    if event.mouseevent.button==1 and isinstance(event.artist, Line2D):
        print("Do the thing.")

def click_handler(event):
    if event.button == 3:
        print("Click_handler called by right-click!")
        # do something

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', pick_handler)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', click_handler)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's already fine, thanks! There is still one cosmetic failure in your suggestion. If I right-click a `Line2D` object in the plot, the `pick_handler()` is still called, because the `print` statement is executed. That does not disturb me, but let me ask out of curiosity – can we entirely avoid calling the `pick_handler()` for **any** right-click?

Comment: No, the pick_handler will always be fired, but what you can do is only act if the correct button is detected.